# Different position in IE8 and IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I have a Problem with the Position of the HTML elements. I am developing a web form.

Until today, I was using IE8 in my Computer (Company issues...) but today I got a new Computer with IE 10.

My problem is that I could see this form perfectly before, but now all elements are moved. For example, the  are move 20px more or less to the top, and if I fix it for IE 10, I can't see it in IE 8 correctly.

My question is if the browser interpret in a different way the position:relative tags? And if it is like that, how could I solve it? The users of this form will use IE8 and 10 too...

I already add to my HTML code the tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7">`

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional comments to apply style to specific browsers:

- gt = greater than
- lt = less than
- lte = less than or equal to
- gte = greater than or equal to

This will target anything greater than IE 8:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gtie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will target anything less than IE 9:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ltie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will target anything that is not internet explorer:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Source:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: But with this solution, I have to develop always my web page with 2 computers, one with IE8 and another with IE10, no?

Comment: Not necessarily, but as different browsers parse and read CSS differently you will have to hack / create different stylesheets to get the same end result. 90% of your css might work for one browser, then for the other browser just provide a different 10% of the css and override using !important ? Just an example

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll implement in that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any [reset style sheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)? If you don't I strongly advise you implement one. I'm afraid, this will almost certainly knock other elements out on your page. It basically gives you a consistent starting point across *all* browsers.

Where posible try avoid adding a whole bunch of browser hacks.